# Should we change the short introduction of this site?

Tags: discussion, editing

In [the list of all site of SE](http://stackexchange.com/sites#newest), there is a one-sentence introduction of this site:

> Q&A for community managers, administrators, and moderators

I just have joined this site yesterday, so I don't know much about its history, but as far as I know, it used to be named as *Moderators*, which is why we have that sentence. However, since the name has changed and the scope opens for members of communities, should we change it? I suggest:

> Q&A for community members and managers

This is also the reason I asked this question: [Is asking about how to get information from a specific site effectively on-topic here?](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1264/is-asking-about-how-to-get-information-from-a-specific-site-effectively-on-topic/1265?noredirect=1#comment1479_1265)

**Update 19 Mar 2015**: Still no change? I want to know the answer.

Comment: Good catch!  That looks like a leftover from before the renaming.  We got the "about" text changed but missed this.

Comment: Expanding this to community members is one thing, but... You probably need to qualify that. "Q&A for community members" sounds pretty circular unless you already know what it's intended to mean.

Comment: @Shog9 so do you have any suggestion?